# Stylus: Interpolate a dynamic ID selector in a webpack configuration

Tags: node.js, webpack, stylus

I want to use an ID Selector in my Stylus file. The problem - the name of the selector shall be set dynamically.

Concrete, i want to retrieve the name of the ID selector from the package.json file of a node.js module. I use webpack as build tool which is running fine.

Example:

package.json

```
{
  "name":"mymodule",
}
```

webpack.config.json

```
var modulname = require('./package.json').name
module.exports = {
  stylus: {
        use: [ ]
  }
}
```

app.styl

```
#{dynamicselctor}
  color: red
  display: flex
```

app.css

```
#modulname
  color: red
  display: flex
```

How to get the `{dynamicselctor}` portion in `app.styl` replaced by the value of the `var modulename` in the `webpack.config.json` which is required from the `package.json` so that the `app.css` is rendered as shown?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `define` stylus-loader option inside your webpack config:

```
var modulname = require('./package.json').name
module.exports = {
  stylus: {
    define: {
      dynamicselctor: modulname
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for you help but the 'dynamicselctor' does not get interpolated. The resulting css is #dynamicselctor ...